# ng-repeat over angularFire rerenders each item

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

Even in the angularFire example chat app at http://angularfire.com/index.html, each element in the ng-repeat seems to be destroyed & recreated in the DOM whenever a new element is added to the list.  In my app the whole list is also rerendered when any of the elements change.

Is this expected?  Is there a way around this, so that only the updated elements are updated?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I'd have thought Angular optimizes away the DOM destroy/create cycles. The `angularFire` service "resets" the whole object on receiving new values from the server, which is likely the cause. You can get around this by using `angularFireCollection` instead, which only modifies the collection incrementally.